# reorder rows in nstableview with drag and drop

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, xcode8, nstableview

i have a nstableview with this 4 rows like this:

```
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 4
```

now i would like to drag item 1 between item 3 and 4 like this:

```
item 2
item 3
item 1 < position after drag and drop
item 4
```

this is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, row: Int, dropOperation: NSTableViewDropOperation) -> Bool {


   let rowData = info.draggingPasteboard().data(forType: NSStringPboardType)
   let dataArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: rowData!) as! Array<IndexSet>
   let draggedItem = rightDataArray[dataArray[0].first!]
   rightDataArray.remove(at: dataArray[0].first!)

   print("Target Row for draggedItem: ",row)

   if row > rightDataArray.endIndex {
      rightDataArray.append(draggedItem)
   } else {
      rightDataArray.insert(draggedItem, at: row)
   }

   self.tableView.reloadData()

   return true

}
```

problem is that my result will be this:

```
item 2
item 3
item 4
item 1 < wrong position after drag and drop
```

The print result:

> Target Row for draggedItem:  3

anybody an idea?

Comment: [NSTableview - Drag and Drop split into two classes and controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387497/4244136)

Comment: sry i saw this to late - thanks for it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSTableview - Drag and Drop split into two classes and controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283444/nstableview-drag-and-drop-split-into-two-classes-and-controllers)